# deviceTheme.js and dojo.js can not be loaded in Chrome

Tags: javascript, dojo

I am following dojo mobile tutorial for [Part 2 - Developing a Dojo Mobile Application: FlickrView](http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.9/mobile/flickrview/part2/).

But when I tried examples in that tutorial, I found that `//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.9.2/dojox/mobile/deviceTheme.js` and `//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.9.2/dojo/dojo.js` can not be loaded in my test html below, these two js file loaded successfully in [demo page](http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.9/mobile/flickrview/part2/demo/mockup2.html)

Am I do something wrong?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,minimum-scale=1,user-scalable=no"/>
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes"/>
    <!-- prevent cache -->
    <meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache">
    <meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache">
    <title>Dojo Mobile tutorial | Flickrview | Part II | HTML Structure</title>
    <!-- application stylesheet -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/flickrview.css">
    <!-- dynamically apply native visual theme according to the browser user agent -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.9.2/dojox/mobile/deviceTheme.js"></script>
    <!-- dojo configuration options -->


    <script type="text/javascript">
        dojoConfig = {
            async : true,
            baseUrl : './',
            parseOnLoad : false,
            mblHideAddressBar : true,
            packages : [{
                name : "flickrview",
                location : "js"
            }]
        };
    </script> 

    <!-- dojo bootstrap -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.9.2/dojo/dojo.js"></script>
    <!-- dojo application code -->
    <script>
        // Load the widget parser and mobile base
        require(["dojox/mobile/parser", "dojox/mobile/compat", "dojo/domReady!"], function(parser) {
            // Parse the page for widgets
            parser.parse();
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- Feed view -->
    <div id="feed" data-dojo-type="dojox/mobile/ScrollableView" data-dojo-props="selected: true">
        <div id="feedHeading"
        data-dojo-type="dojox/mobile/Heading"
        data-dojo-props="fixed: 'top', label: 'Feeds'">
            <span data-dojo-type="dojox/mobile/ToolBarButton"
            data-dojo-props="icon: 'images/settings.png', moveTo:'settings', transitionDir:'-1', transition:'none'"
            style="float:left;"></span>
            <span id="refreshButton" data-dojo-type="dojox/mobile/ToolBarButton"
            data-dojo-props="icon: 'images/refresh.png'"
            style="float:right;"></span>
        </div>
        <div id="feedList" data-dojo-type="dojox/mobile/EdgeToEdgeList">
            <div data-dojo-type="dojox/mobile/ListItem"
            data-dojo-props="moveTo:'details', transition:'slide'" class="photoListItem">
                <img src="images/photo1.png" width="80px" height="80px" alt="Title" style="float:left;"/>
                <div class="photoSummary">
                    <div class="photoTitle">
                        Photo title here
                    </div>
                    <div class="publishedTime" data-dojo-time="2013-12-13">
                        published date here
                    </div>
                    <div class="author">
                        author here
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="summaryClear"></div>
            </div>
            <div data-dojo-type="dojox/mobile/ListItem"
            data-dojo-props="moveTo:'details', transition:'slide'" class="photoListItem">
                <img src="images/photo2.png" width="80px" height="80px" alt="Title" style="float:left;"/>
                <div class="photoSummary">
                    <div class="photoTitle">
                        Another photo title here
                    </div>
                    <div class="publishedTime" data-dojo-time="2013-12-13">
                        published date here
                    </div>
                    <div class="author">
                        author here
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="summaryClear"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Here's error message in Chrome.
[image: error message in Chrome]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use the protocol-less version of the url (like `//ajax.googleapis.com`) you have to **host** your project somewhere (either on a local or a remote webserver).

You can not just open the file (using the `file://` prefixed URL), because then it won't be able to find the specified libraries. What actually happens if you load such a URL is that the same protocol-prefix is used to load these pages. If you load a page just by opening the file, it will have a `file://` prefix and not `http://` or `https://`.

This is also the reason why it is working on the demo page (because it is hosted) and why you get these `GET` errors, it's trying to find `ajax.googleapis.com` on your local machine (due to the `file://` protocol), which it obviously can't find.

To fix it you just use the full URL, for example:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.9.2/dojo/dojo.js"></script>
```

Or a better solution is to put your project on a webserver (nginx, apache2, ...), because I don't think you will be able to load asynchronous modules either.

Comment: After added `http://` before url of src attibute, it works. Thanks a lot for your help.